# Accessing Sharepoint List with JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, javascript

I've been using the code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx) with a few modifications for my own code to access a list on my SharePoint site through JavaScript. This script is in the ASP.Net for the initiation form of a workflow on the site. I have seen lots of other answers for this but not any that have worked for me. I've inserted alerts into the code and found that it is running through the whole thing, but the issue is that when getList() function finishes running, the listItemInfo array is empty.

```
var listItemInfo = [];

window.onload = function()
{
    populateCatalystComboBox();
};

function populateCatalystComboBox()
{
    var catalystList = [];
    var index = 0;
    var select = document.getElementById("catalystSelections");

    getList();

    document.getElementById("testLabel").innerHTML = listItemInfo[0];
    alert ("Here");
    for (var i=0; i<listItemInfo.length; i++)
    {
        index = listItemInfo[i].indexOf("Chemical Type: ") + 14;
        if (listItemInfo[i].substring(index) == "Catalyst")
        {
            catalystList.push(listItemInfo[i]);
        }
    }

    catalystList.push("Test 3");
    catalystList.push("Test 4");

    //document.getElementById("testLabel").innerHTML = (catalystList.toString());

    for (i=0; i<catalystList.length; i++)
    {
        var catalyst = catalystList[i];
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.textContent = catalyst;
        newOption.value = catalyst;
        select.appendChild(newOption);
    }
}

function getList()
{
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("https://____.sharepoint.com/sites/______/");
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ChemicalsTable');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo.push ('\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body'));
    }

    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

The alert "Here" does display and the innerHTML = listItemInfo[0] becomes "undefined".

UPDATE:
I've found that when I insert an alert(oListItem.get_id()); in onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) in the while loop it outputs the correct data. However, when I put in alert(oListItem.get_item('ChemicalName'));, the alert doesn't pop up. It is instead popping up with an alert that the column name (ChemicalName) doesn't exist. The problem is, it does. The URL is the one for my site, it paths to Site Contents->Lists->Chemicals Table as it should where there is a column named ChemicalName.

Comment: If you want to retrieve data from `listItemInfo` as if it were an array, you need to define it as an array (`var listItemInfo = []`), and use `.push()` instead of concatenating a string (`+=`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I had fixed that before but for some reason it reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to run  `jsom` without loaded `sp.js`

try to call `sp.js` before running any `jsom` function as the following

```
 $(document).ready(function () {     
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', prepareTables);
    });
```

so remove

```
window.onload = function()
{
    populateCatalystComboBox();
};
```

and replace it with

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', prepareTables);
            populateCatalystComboBox();
        });
```

Comment: I get this when I run your code: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Are you add JQuery reference

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Would I add this statement in before the script I have or would I add in src="..." to the script I am using.

Comment: at the top of front code , or you can use it without jquery as the following :  window.onload = function()
{SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', prepareTables);
            populateCatalystComboBox();};

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: prepare tables is not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43761/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-ulthran).

Answer (score 2):

Please try with using defered and promise on function getList() 
 as it is asyn call, you can refer [link](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/10/sharepoint-using-deferredspromises-or.html) for using defered.SharePoint JavaScript client object model is asynchronous. However, sometimes  we want to process things in synchronous way. This can be done by using  JavaScript call backs and deferreds/Promises.